# Problem with switching solenoid valve by relay

Tags: arduino, resistors, diodes, relay, electromagnetism

I've been trying to drive a 12volt solenoidal valve with a 5volt relay .Relay is working perfectly for driving normal loads(light bulbs).But it is not driving my 12volt solenoidal valve.
I've already connected a fly back protection diode across solenoidal valve.

My circuit almost looks like these....
[image]

The source used is 12volt not 24 and dashed box is a microcontroller circuit .Sorry for not including these.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please draw _exactly_ how it’s connected and what you have measured.

Comment: You are driving a 12v solenoid valve with 24v according to your drawing. What is the dashed box?

Comment: Please include more of the stuff inside the dashed box, specifically the MCU, the I/O pin, and everything out to the relay including actual part numbers.

Comment: @RonBeyer the dashed box have nothing to do with the problem .I've tried different methods to turn on the relay beside my microcontroler circuit and still the problem arises

Comment: Solenoid valve problem?

Comment: @vu2nan valve is working when supply is directly connected ,but issue while connecting with relay...

Comment: What is the contact rating of the 5V relay and the resistance of the 12V solenoid?

Comment: diode D1 have to be connected to power supply not to microcontroller pin... in the way you connect it the overvoltage is going to MCU pin.